# Disable Eclipse auto-save of the perspective

Tags: eclipse, perspective

Currently, every time I move a window, the new position is saved in the perspective.

When I want to restore the perspective (as it was when I saved it), **it doesn't do a thing**, because the perspective was saved with my modifications.

I want to disable this behavior, how can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restore the perspective as it was when you saved it, you have to *reset* it.  Reset actually means restore to default but when you save a perspective and overwrite the current settings for this perspective what you actually do is change its defaults.

For instance,

1. Open eclipse Java perspective; say this is layout "A".
2. change the layout of your views in the java perspective
3. Do windows => save perspective as => java => confirm overwrite (this is when you change the defaults).  Let's call this new layout "B".
4. Change again the layout. Say this is now layout "C".
5. Close eclipse.
6. Open eclipse again, you should have layout "C" (last known to eclipse).
7. window => reset perspective => confirm.  You should see the layout back to "B".

Layout "A" is lost of course, and so is the previous default Java perspective layout.

Comment: THANK YOU !! I feel silly now, but still it's not intuitive. Thanks a lot (switching from 2 screens to 1 would mess up all my window placements, but now I'm happy)

Comment: I agree this "reset" is counter intuitive. It suggests you're going back to "factory settings" so to say ;-)